# .htaccess to remove arbitrary text in filenames

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got a client who uploads thousands of images with names like `1057_1.jpg` , `1057_2.jpg`, `1083_1H.jpg` etc - always a number, an underscore, a number and an optional letter. The CMS uses these to link them to relevant entries.

For SEO reasons we want those image filenames to contain some keywords taken from the CMS. So they would become, say, `1057_1-some-keywords-here.jpg`. Is there a way, with .htaccess, to keep the filenames the same, but redirect `1057_1-any-arbitrary-words.jpg` to `1057_1.jpg`? Basically to remove everything from the first dash up to the dot?

Thanks for your help - I must learn htaccess properly sometime but need to find a quick solution for now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /([^\-]+)-.+\.([^/]+)/?
RewriteRule .*    %1.%2     [R=301,L]
```

Redirects permanently any URL like:

`http://example.com/1057_1-anything.jpg` or

`http://example.com/any/number/of/folders/1057_1-anything.jpg`

To:

`http://example.com/1057_1.jpg` or

`http://example.com/any/number/of/folders/1057_1.jpg`

Effectively removing `-anything` from the **last string** in the URL-path.

The image name hast to be the **last string** in the URL-path, for the rule-set to work.

For a silent mapping, remove `R=301` from `[R=301,L]`.

#### UPDATE:

`anything` did not include the period as it was used to determine the end of the name and the start of the extension. However, I modified the rule-set to remove also any number of periods in `anything` except the last one, according to the OP requirement in previous comment.

Comment: Thanks faa! That works great - I put it in my images folder so that it wouldn't effect anything else on the site (I guess that works?) and it seems to be working perfectly. Just to be sure: removing R=301 means that google will think that there is actually a file called http://example.com/any/number/of/folders/1057_1-anything.jpg ? And leaving it there will let google know that the actual file is called http://example.com/any/number/of/folders/1057_1.jpg ? I'm guessing for SEO I want the former...

Comment: Ah sorry, I've just found that some of the long filenames will include periods, so they might be something like http://example.com/any/folders/1057_1-anything-including.periods.jpg - but they will always end in ".jpg". Is there an easy way to modify the above to allow for that? Thank you!

Comment: @Frank Updated my answer. Please check it.

Comment: @Frank Regarding your first comment, it doesn't make any difference for SEO but it does for the site. So, keep them visible (With R=301), the URLS are shorter and "pretty".

Comment: Thanks faa - that's perfect! Much appreciated.